# custom post type loop not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to create a custom loop from the metadata I have entered into the posts.

```
<?php $args = array (

    'post_type'     => array( 'movies' ),
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'order_by'      => 'get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "released", true )',

);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

bd_pagination();

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

I so so need help plz

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your parameters a bit. I'm assuming the "released" is a date field? If not (eg, if it's a timestamp), use a numeric orderby instead. But this should set you on your way:

```
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'movies' ),
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_date',
  'meta_key'  => 'released',
  'meta_type' => 'DATE'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: But in what format is the data? That will determine whether you use "DATE" or "NUMERIC" or whatever for your sorting. For example, if the meta data is 10152007 and 01041998 as dates, you'd want to use meta_value_num and NUMERIC to sort on that. Make sense?

Comment: array(
                'id'   => 'released',
                'name' => __( 'Release Date', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'date',
            ),